# Sorting with MongoDB full text search

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for a way to sort results by value of a field while performing a full text search with mongodb 2.4.

My text search command looks something like this:

```
db.books.runCommand( "text", { search: "science" } )
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
db.books.runCommand( "text", { search: "science", "sort": "rating" } )
```

I can see in the documentation that a limit parameter exists, but not something to sort results by other than the default sort by relevance score.

Re sorting the results is probably going to be inefficient. What is a good way to get this done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB text search and order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336391/mongodb-text-search-and-order-by)

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, managed to solve the problem (pymongo) by using instead of the runCommand stuff the '$meta' operator:

```
# create text index
db.collection.ensure_index([("textField", "text")], name = "Text_search_index")    
# query     
queryDict = { "$text": { "$search": ""science"}}    
# cursor
cursor = db.collection.find(queryDict, {'score': {'$meta': 'textScore'}, "_id":1}).sort([('score', {'$meta': 'textScore'})]).limit(limit_value)
```

Looks like this is available only [from 2.6 version](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/cursor.py#L658) at least in pymongo

Also in Mongo shell this equivalent to :

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"textField":"text"})    
queryDict = { "$text": { "$search": "science"}}    
db.collection.find(queryDict, {'score': {'$meta': 'textScore'}}).sort({'score': {'$met
a': 'textScore'}}).limit(100)
```

Comment: Also if you have "TypeError: second item in each key pair must be 1, -1, '2d', 'geoHaystack', or another valid MongoDB index specifier". Consider installing latest version of pymongo driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, works with MongoDB 4.4:

```
collection.find({
        $text:
          {
            $search: filter,
            $caseSensitive: false,
            $diacriticSensitive: true
          }
        })
        .project({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
        .sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

Comment: what about earlier versions?

Comment: @MH.Abdi The aggregate function has support for text index score sorting