# Multiple criteria possible in one query inside MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've a "words" collection in MongoDB. When I want to search the collection I want to list first words that starts with the "word" and then contains the "word" that I querid. In the same array I get this result; "simarte", "Cumartesti", "Mart", "marti", "martilar". When I search with contains it brings me other words that contains the "word" (mart).

I want to order first the words that starts with the "word" than order "contains" the words. Is it possible to do that in one query? I don't want to make a second request to db.

Here is my code sample:

```
    var word = "mart";
    db.words.find({"w" : {$regex : ".*" + word + ".*"}}, function(err, words) {
      if( err || !words) console.log("No data found");
      else{
       res.render('index', { title: 'Words', word_data: words, word : word });
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible, since if you sort by `w` field, mongodb will consider the first letter to sort (and the second if first is equals, etc).

Maybe text search could help you. It contains a `score` field in results and you can sort by it. As @WiredPrairie pointed, Text Search isn't production ready, so be careful.
Another option is sort results programmatically.

Here you can find more info about that:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/

[Sorting with MongoDB full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312538/sorting-with-mongodb-full-text-search)

Comment: Text search isn't production ready, so I wouldn't recommend it yet.