# MongoDB text search and order by

Tags: mongodb

We're using MongoDB's text search, which so far is working great.  However, we want to also specify an order for the results, such as this:

```
db.items.runCommand("text", {search: "\"test item\"", "$orderby" : { votes : 1 }});
```

This executes, but it doesn't sort by votes, it's still ordered by the score.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: text search doesn't support custom sorting so you'd have to sort the results by `votes` in your own code.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you - can you answer with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB's `"text"` command doesn't support custom sorting so you'd have to sort the results by `votes` in your own code.

The supported options are listed [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/).