# pymongo remove with user defined parameters

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to build a simple `mongodb` RESTful API. Client will send JSON data for document removal, which looks like this:

```
{
    "collectionName": "user",
    "data": {
        "field": "fname",
        "value": "Mike"
    },
    "options": {
        "multi": "false"
    }
}
```

I would like to pass `options` from this JSON to `pymongo`'s `.remove()` function but it's not working. I've tried it like this:

```
opts = {u'multi': u'false'}
dataBase[collectionName].remove({"some":"condition"},multi=opts['multi'])
```

it removes all documents that match the given condition, but multi should be false.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see `multi` listed as a supported option in [the pymongo docs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336391/mongodb-text-search-and-order-by) for `remove`.

Comment: Omg...I've totally overlooked that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyMongo's remove() method doesn't support the "multi" option. The option will be added in the next release of PyMongo, version 2.7. Details are in ticket [PYTHON-605](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-605).